# How can I use particle analysis in dm-script for a images dataset?

Tags: dm-script

I have two datasets, one with 884 images and other with 1057 images; the datasets came from in situ heating experiment. I have processed the data (cross-correlation, filtering and so forth).  Now, I have two datasets of binary images. I need to measure the number of particles, area and aspect ratio of each particle in each image (that I can do using particles analysis in the tool menu of Digital micrograph). I need to connect the measures trough my whole dataset, which means, one particle measured in one image needs to be the same particle in the other image. I believe that is not a trivial task. However, does anyone else has any idea how can I advance in this task?

Comment: I'm afraid this is rather an application question than a *coding* question. This site is for questions on how DM scripting code works, not how one achieves a particular application.

Comment: Thank you for point out my mistake. I apologize for that.

Comment: An application framework based on DM-script that I am currently developing may be able to provide some tools that would help streamline the development task before you.  It is specifically directed towards microscopy data analysis applications.  If you would be interested in a collaborative effort, please contact me via the info on my profile page.

Answer (score 1):

The following information might be useful in your endeavour:

> Script-access to the ParticleAnalysis functionality of
>   DigitalMicrograph was added in **GMS 3** with the 
>   `FindParticles` command.

There is no documentation (yet), but the following script example demonstrates the method.

Some notes:

- The mask image as well as the foundParticlesImage require to be of type binary
- The returned image document contains the results as a spread-sheet in the way also the menu returns one

**Example:**

```
image inputImage := GetFrontImage()
number sx, sy
getsize( inputImage, sx, sy )

image mask := BinaryImage( "Binary Mask", sx, sy )      // The real input for analysis
Image foundParticlesImage := BinaryImage( "found", sx, sy ) // Accepted particles mask (result)

mask = inputImage>0.6*max(inputImage) ? 1 : 0           // This is a simple Treshold to test...

string mFields = "Area,FilledArea,CenterX"      // Specify analysis results
Number minParticleSize = 15                     // Limit accepted
Number doLabel = 0                              // Add labeled mask to inputImage True/False

imageDocument ResultsDoc = FindParticles(inputImage,mask,mFields, minParticleSize, doLabel, foundParticlesImage)
ImageDocumentShow( ResultsDoc )

Showimage( mask )
ShowImage( foundParticlesImage )
```

---

You might also find the following useful:

> Script-access to binary image processing is part of DigitalMicrograph since **GMS 1** already. The commands reflect the Analysis menu options: 
>   `MPOpen`, `MPClose`, `MPErode`, `MPDilate`, `MPOutline`, `MPDistanceMap`, `MPEuclideanDistanceMap`, `MPExactDistanceMap`.

All of these commands require mask images to be of type binary.

**Example:**

```
image CreateMPCloseStack( image maskInput, number neighbors, number iterations )
{
    number sx, sy
    GetSize( maskInput, sx, sy )
    image maskBinary := BinaryImage( "mask", sx, sy )
    maskBinary = maskInput
    image outStack := BinaryImage( "Stack", sx, sy, iterations + 1 )
    for( number n=0; n<= iterations; n++ )
    {
        outStack[0,0,n,sx,sy,n+1] = maskBinary
        maskBinary = MPClose( maskBinary, neighbors )
    }
    return outStack
}

image maskInput := GetFrontImage()
ShowImage( CreateMPCloseStack( maskInput, 5, 10 ) )
```